# Groupby function gives me a table, not a series form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

df:

```
    id  cond1   a   b   c   d
0   Q   b       1   1   nan 1
1   R   b       8   3   nan 3
2   Q   a       12  4   8   nan
3   Q   b       8   3   nan 1
4   R   b       1   2   nan 3
5   Q   a       7   9   8   nan
6   Q   b       4   4   nan 1
7   R   b       9   8   nan 3
8   Q   a       0   10  8   nan
```

Group by id and cond1 and do a rolling(2).sum():

```
df.groupby(['id','cond1']).apply(lambda x: x[x.name[1]].rolling(2).sum())
```

Output:

```
id  cond1   
Q   a      2                    nan
           5               19.00000
           8                7.00000
    b      0                    nan
           3                4.00000
           6                7.00000
R   b      1                    nan
           4                5.00000
           7               10.00000
dtype: float64
```

Why is the output in a table form? Can it be in a series form and its index reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reset_index()` to make `groupby` object back to `dataframe`

Comment: Okay, this worked. `df.groupby(['id','cond1']).apply(lambda x: x[x.name[1]].rolling(2).sum()).reset_index().set_index('level_2').sort_index()`